# Is there an algorithm to find all subgraphs of a graph in which every vertex is reachable from a source vertex and reaches a destination vertex?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Say we have a directed graph. I want to find all subgraphs in which:

- Every vertex is reachable from a single source vertex, and
- Every vertex can be used to reach a single destination vertex.

Does an algorithm exist to accomplish this? Thanks.